# Google Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) timeout error

Tags: php, session, google-cloud-platform, google-iap

I host a PHP web app on google cloud and protect it with Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP).

Now, I'm running into the timeout issue because IAP doesn't seems to follow php session time.

Following is the phpinfo() for session timeout.

[image: php information]

The app only last around 40 mins and ask the user to login again or get 401 error when accessing the server from Ajax.

I need it to be last for around 4-8 hr. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. See https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/sessions-howto for the workaround, or follow https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69386592 for updates on a permanent solution.

Comment: Hi @Matthew Saches,  Thanks for the workaround. I tried both solutions and the second one work for the desktop browser. But my main application is using via android tablet with "<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">". So it open on a separate full screen window. I tried to load the page[https://yourapp/_gcp_iap/session_refresher] on main chrome browser but it is not working.  Any idea how can i achieve this workaround on mobile web page?

Comment: I'd expect #1 to work in that environment, though I haven't tested it. I don't suppose you're able to use https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_mobile_app ?

Comment: I'm positive that #1 is not working. Already tested. For #2, I added the link inside the app and let user open this link before using the app. 

Most of the time it is working. Sometime still got timeout error. If it happen, I request user to go and refresh the session_refresher tab that they open at the start. 

Too much hacky but at least my app is not breaking. Would love Google to fix this one.

Comment: Just to update that #1 not working can be due to the iframe not refreshing. Even on the #2 workaround, the user still need go and refresh the page sometime while the session timeout.